# WASM memory access out of bounds using threejs DracoLoader on Mobile Browsers

Tags: memory, three.js, webassembly

I’m currently running into an issue where I’m trying to load a Draco compressed model using the Draco Loader of threejs on mobile browsers and it seems to hard crash during the call to the `.load method. IOS Safari not and Chrome version 88.0.4324.93 on an Android - Pixel 2 XL are the ones I’ve tested so far. The exact same models seem to render completely fine on web browsers with no issues.

This is a screenshot of the error I’m receiving which states memory access out of bounds

```
RuntimeError: memory access out of bounds
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[377]:0x18a28
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[358]:0x170b9
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[354]:0x16f17
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[446]:0x21f40
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[323]:0x1371f
    at <anonymous>:wasm-function[23]:0x2cb1
    at emscripten_bind_Decoder_DecodeBufferToMesh_2 (<anonymous>:wasm-function[119]:0x934e)
    at a._emscripten_bind_Decoder_DecodeBufferToMesh_2 (blob:https://bdd35c37d00a.ngrok.io/95a82b20-81cc-451e-a630-f47694de7a0f:51:560)
    at g.DecodeBufferToMesh.g.DecodeBufferToMesh (blob:https://bdd35c37d00a.ngrok.io/95a82b20-81cc-451e-a630-f47694de7a0f:92:54)
    at decodeGeometry (blob:https://bdd35c37d00a.ngrok.io/95a82b20-81cc-451e-a630-f47694de7a0f:189:29)
```

I’ve tried adding console logs to the onProgress, onLoad, and onError callbacks. The onProgress seems to fully complete but after that, before the onLoad callback can run, it crashes and the onError callback isn’t called either.

Anyone have any ideas on how to go about solving this?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: How large is the model you are trying to load? Could it be that the model is simply too large for the memory on the phone?

Comment: @2pha 50.9MB after Draco compression so I don't quite think it's the case. The size of the heap snapshot on web Chrome after loading the model is only around ~360MB. Could it potentially be something having to do with the available buffer cache memory or something when decompressing the model?

Comment: a 50Mb draco is very large. I have never had to deal with this, so I am just guessing sorry. Maybe it's a gpu memory issue? Though I am not sure if phones have a separate gpu memory.

Comment: Not sure as well but at any rate, it's seemingly like the simplest solution is to try and reduce the size of the models. Appreciate the input and responses though. Thank you!